# Is it possible to authenticate Outlook users with certificates on RPC over HTTPS?

Tags: exchange, outlook, login, certificate

I would like to understand the possibility to limit access from Internet to Exchange (RPC over HTTPS in Outlook) by requiring the machine or user to present a client certificate (before the login session).
Is this at all possible with Exchange 2010?

I saw a lot of docs for the Active Sync part (where this is possible) but I just recall seeing once a technical document for client certificate authentication with RPC over HTTPS (and frankly speaking, I am not that sure I saw it, since I cannot find it again despite repeated searches).

Alternatively: is it possible to request an NTLM token as the sole authentication mechanism (which would be available only from a domain controller, thus rejecting machines from outside the domain)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely use NTLM auth, especially if you only have users connecting that are logging on with their domain credentials to their workstations (even cached credentials).

> **NTLM authentication**: If you select this authentication type, exchange does not prompt users for a user name and password. The
>   current Windows user information on the client computer is supplied by
>   the browser through a cryptographic exchange involving hashing with
>   the Web server. If the authentication exchange initially fails to
>   identify the user, the browser will prompt the user for a Windows user
>   account user name and password. So, when Outlook is trying to connect
>   to Exchange and if the machine is domain joined, there isn’t a need to
>   provide password.

You can't use a client cert that I'm aware of.  I don't think Outlook has a means of passing the cert along.  If you look at the auth mehthods, the only thing close to this would be a 2-factor auth using a smart card.

Links:

[Configure Authentication for Outlook Anywhere](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb124149%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx)

[Configure Smart Card Authentication for Outlook Anywhere](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh227263.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, this is very instructive. I see however that _"If the authentication exchange initially fails to identify the user, the browser will prompt the user for a Windows user account user name and password"_. Would you know if there is a way to disable this, i.e. to allow only NTLM authentication and reject the connection otherwise?

Comment: That I don't know (without digging).  The reason they do this is in case you aren't domain joined (home computer for CEO for example).